Timezone Conversion from UTC to User Time Zone, on Prod vs. Dev?
I have this node.js code.
import {toZonedTime} from 'date-fns-tz' 

function utcHoursToUserTimeZone_date(utcTimeslot, targetDay, userTimeZone) {
    const [hour, minute] = utcTimeslot.split(":").map(Number);

    // NOTE: hour == 0. minute == 0.
    // Hour is UTC time, meaning midnight UTC, which would equal, e.g.
    // 8pm in time zone "America/New_York"
    // ----
    // userTimeZone == 'America/New_York"
    // targetDay == 2, i.e. Tuesday

    // Create a Date object for the given time in UTC
    let date = new Date();
    date.setUTCHours(hour, minute, 0, 0);  // Set the hours and minutes in UTC directly
    date = setDay(date, targetDay);
    date = toZonedTime(date, userTimeZone);

    console.log('in utcHoursToUserTimeZone_date. date: ', date)

    return date;
}

My dev system is in time zone "America/New_York". When I run this on my dev system, date returns as:

2024-10-02T00:00:00.000Z

My production server is in time zone "UTC".  When I run this on my production server, date returns as:

2024-09-30T20:00:00.000Z

I thought I was fixing this with toZonedTime(date, userTimeZone);. What am I missing?
